# Most efficient practices you will quickly do to recover/re-generate Bodhicitta and/or right view of Śūnyatā if realizing losing mindfulness of?

Tags: personal-practice, mahayana, sunyata, bodhisattva-vows

In daily (secular) life, if you realize that you are being or have been losing (or forgetting) mindfulness of Bodhicitta and/or right view of Śūnyatā, what (most efficient practices) you will quickly do to recover/re-generate Bodhicitta and/or right view of Śūnyatā in you?

Thanks in advance for any possible answer and/or instruction for the question in this post you can and will give.

P.S. I am unsure having figure out a good title for this post so everyone is welcome to help.

Comment: The distraction probably needs more emphasis than sunyata. What is the distraction?

Comment: @Max Hi thanks for begin discussion! So using "distracted" causes unclear meaning? Then, maybe that "distracted from" should be replaced by "losing/forgetting mindfulness of". I try edit it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need a new or special practice for this; just take a moment and do a light version of regular practice. For instance, you might stop and focus your attention on your breathing for a minute, just watching it come and go without changing it. You don't need to sit on a cushion, find a 'clear' space, or do any of the other things you would do for a normal meditation session; you don't even need to put down anything you might be holding. Just pause, pay attention to six or seven breaths, and go back to whatever you were doing.

You'll sometimes hear people talk about 'centering' or 'grounding'. That is essentially what I'm suggesting, and you might find some other practical techniques if you google around. Full meditation sessions establish and deepen the practice, but in between such sessions we still want to bring ourselves back to center, just a touch of practice on the fly to remind ourselves.